# Do you know the reason for this anomaly in JS DOM parser scope?

Tags: javascript, xml, domparser

Good afternoon. Although logging to the console produces the desired result... logging the final array shows that only the last child has been pushed into the loop.

What am I misunderstanding about the scope of this object variable?

```
let arr = [];
let obj = {};
parser = new DOMParser();
xml = parser.parseFromString(xml,"text/xml");
let root = xml.children[0];
for (var i = 0; i < root.children.length; i++) {
  let child = root.children[i].children;
  for (var i2 = 0; i2 < task.length; i2++) {
    obj[child[i2].nodeName] = child[i2].textContent;
  };
  // arr[i] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)); // WHY IS THIS NECESSARY???
  arr.push(obj); 
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); // LOGS EACH CHILD CORRECTLY; FINAL ARRAY DOES NOT!
};
console.log(JSON. stringify(arr)); // RESULT IS THE LAST NODE NAME/VALUE REPEATED i TIMES
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));

This instruction creates a clone of `obj`. As `obj` is defined and assigned before the loop (and not reassigned afterwards), if you don't do that then you're always putting the same object instance into your array. You're also aggregating all `nodeNames` information in the same object.

If you don't want to do that, you could define `obj` inside the loop :

```
let arr = [];
parser = new DOMParser();
xml = parser.parseFromString(xml,"text/xml");
let root = xml.children[0];

for (let i = 0; i < root.children.length; i++) {
    let obj = {};
    let child = root.children[i].children;
    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < task.length; i2++) {
        obj[child[i2].nodeName] = child[i2].textContent;
    };
    arr.push(obj); 
    console.log(obj);
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

However, as a consequence of this, you won't get a final object at the end of the loops with all informations about each children, like you had in your previous example.